# Show that: exists unique ring homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} [ i ] \longrightarrow R$ with $\varphi ( i ) = a$, where $a^{2} =-1_{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism, universal-property, gaussian-integers

**Problem:** Let R be a ring which has an element $a \in R$ such that $a^{2}=-1_{R}$.
Prove that: there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} [ i ] \longrightarrow R$ such that $\varphi ( i ) = a$.

So, $\mathbb{Z} [ i ]$ has the above *Universal Property.*

*Note that:
$\mathbb{Z} [ i ]$ denote the ring of Gauss integers, where $\mathbb{Z} [ i ] = \big \{ a + b i : a , b \in \mathbb{Z} \big \}$ with $i^{2}=-1$ the imaginary unit
or otherwise
is the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z} [ x ] / < x^{2} + 1 > \cong \mathbb{Z} [ i ]$, where $\mathbb{Z} [ x ]$ is the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients and $< x^{2} + 1 > = \big \{ (x^{2} + 1) f ( x ) : f ( x ) \in \mathbb{Z} [ x ] \big \}$ the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^{2} + 1$.*

*How can I solve this problem? I'm stuck, please give me a hand.*

I have done the following:
\begin{align*}
\varphi \Big( \big( x + y i \big) + \big( z + t i \big) \Big)
=
\varphi \Big( \big( x + z \big) + \big( y + t \big) i \Big)
=
\varphi \big( x + z \big) + \varphi \big( y + t \big) a
=
\\
=
\big( \varphi ( x ) + \varphi ( y ) a \big) + \big( \varphi ( z ) + \varphi ( t ) a \big)
=
\\
=
\varphi \big( x + y i \big) + \varphi \big( z + t i \big)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\varphi \Big( \big( x + y i \big) \big( z + t i \big) \Big)
=
\varphi \Big( \big( x z - y t \big) + \big( x t + y z \big) i \Big)
=
\varphi \big( x z - y t \big) + \varphi \big( x t + y z \big) a
=
\\
=
\varphi ( x ) \varphi ( z ) - \varphi ( y ) \varphi( t ) + \Big[ \varphi ( x ) \varphi ( t ) + \varphi ( y ) \varphi ( z ) \Big] a
=
\\
=
\big( \varphi ( x ) + \varphi ( y ) a \big) \big( \varphi ( z ) + \varphi ( t ) a \big)
=
\\
=
\varphi \big( x + y a \big) \varphi \big( z + t a \big).
\end{align*}

Am I correct about that $\varphi$ is ring homomorphism?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like there are two steps:  (1) show that such a hom $\varphi$ exists, then (2) show that there is only one. Where is your work toward these steps?

Comment: As a hint. To construct a homomorphism from $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$ to $R$, first construct a homomorphism from $\Bbb Z[x]$ to $R$, then show that it sends $x^2 + 1$ to zero.

Comment: @Randall I tried to prove that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, but I failed because I do not know the type of $\varphi$, for example $\varphi(1)=1_{R}$ and $\varphi(i)=a$ but what can we do with that $\varphi(x+yi)=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)a$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preliminary facts.**

1. For any ring $R$, there is a unique homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to R$.
2. Fixed a ring $K$, for any choice of a ring $R$, a homomorphism $\phi:K\to R$ and an element $a\in R$, there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi :K[X]\to R$ such that $\varphi(X)=a$ and $\phi(k)=\varphi(k)$ for all $k\in K$.
3. (1) and (2) imply that, for any choice of a ring $R$ and an element $a\in R$, there is a unique homomorphism $\alpha:\mathbb Z[X]\to R$ such that $\alpha(X)=a$.

**Existence.** Let's prove that, given a ring $R$ and $a\in R$ satisfying $a^2+1=0$, there is a homomorphism $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)\to R$ sending the residue class of $X$ to $a$. By (3) there is a homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z[X]\to R$ such that $f(X)=a$. Let $\pi:\mathbb Z[X]\to \mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)$ be the canonical homomorphism: since $f(X^2+1)=a^2+1=0$, the universal property of the quotient yields a homomorphism $f':\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)\to R$ such that $f'\circ \pi=f$ (so $f'$ sends the residue class of $X$ to $a$).

**Uniqueness.** If a homomorphism $g:\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)\to R$ sends the residue class of $X$ to $a$, then $g\circ \pi$ sends $X$ to $a$, hence coincides with $f$ by (3). But also $f'\circ \pi=f$, so by the universal property of the quotient $g=f'$.